# How to draw histogram in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I need to make a histogram in gnuplot, it needs to look something like this:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY0c3.png).
I've tried this:

```
set style fill solid 0.85 border lt -1
p 'file.txt' u 1:2 w boxes lc rgb "blue"
```

It says:

```
warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
                                                 ^
         all points y value undefined!
```

And here is the data file:

```
O 200  
B 19480
A 72156
F 51747
G 50757
K 71804
M 5445
```

When I change letters with numbers there's no error but nothing happens.

Comment: Okay fixed it, just add third column with numbers 1 to 7 and use 
set xtics ("O" 1, "B" 2, "A" 3, "F" 4, "G" 5, "K" 6, "M" 7)

Comment: Problem solved? Any response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can have it simpler without adding an extra column by using `xtic(1)` (check `help xticlabels`) and the pseudocolumn 0 (check `help pseudocolumns`).

**Code:**

```
### column as xtic labels
reset session

$Data <<EOD
O 200
B 19480
A 72156
F 51747
G 50757
K 71804
M 5445 
EOD

set xlabel "Spectral type"
set ylabel "Number"
unset key

set offset 0.7,0.7,0.0,0.7
set style fill solid 0.85 border lt -1
plot $Data u 0:2:xtic(1) w boxes lc rgb "blue"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]